# Running a Query in PHPmyadmin in wp_users table in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

When i log in to my wordpress admin using a webbrowser using admin/admin123 as password it works great.

**I tried to run the following query in phpymadmin,**

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users where user_login='admin' and user_pass=MD5('admin123');
```

it says

**"MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0003 sec )"**

Not sure what the issue is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress does not use a simple md5 password.
You also should not use md5 as password protection its bad. A quick google search will teach you that.

Handy fact, if you lose your password you can enter an md5 password in the DB and WP will accept it on login and rehash it to its own safe password hash